# preg_match with hyphen allowed

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am working with a hashtag, and I need it to accept a - as well as characters. The issue is when the link is created a - will break it.
Example
#something-else

Will link to https://noname.com/activity-2/?hashtag=something

When I want it to point to https://noname.com/activity-2/?hashtag=something-else

```
    function hashtag_links( $content ) {
    $content = ' '.$content;
    preg_match_all( '/ #(\w+)/u', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    if ( isset( $matches[0] ) && is_array( $matches[0] ) ) {
        foreach ( $matches as $match ) {
            $link = '<strong onclick="window.location.assign(\'' . add_query_arg( 'hashtag', $match[1], um_get_core_page( 'activity' ) ) . '\'); return false;" class="um-link">#' . $match[1] . '</strong>';
            $content = str_replace( '#' . $match[1], $link, $content );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: No examples to test with? Did you try with groups like `/[a-zA-Z\-]/`?

Comment: "Breaks the link" - you mean a line break? Or do you mean your regex only finds part of the word?

Comment: So space, hash tag, then word character or a dash? `[-\w]` should be it

Comment: I added some additional information, thanks.

Comment: I think https://regex101.com/r/zMP6oW/1 works

Comment: `\w` will match word-characters only. `-` breaks a word, so your pattern isn't covering the full match, just up to the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a leading or trailing hyphen, you can use:

```
#\K\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `#` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so fer
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:-\w+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and again 1+ word chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ql36D5/1)

Then you can use the match at index 0 instead of the capture group.